# Tomcat does not undeploy one jar

Tags: tomcat, deployment, jar

I am using Tomcat 5. And I am using manager application to undeploy a war file from remote.
It deletes war file and all extracted files. But it does not delete one jar (*lib/struts.jar*) file. I do not know what the reason is. I need to delete all the files even if Tomcat is running. Thanks.

Comment: Are you running tomcat on windows by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this problem with Struts 1.3.8 but it was fixed in 1.3.10. If you are using the old Struts, please upgrade.

Here is the related bug,

http://issues.apache.org/struts/browse/STR-3143

Add `antiResourceLocking="true"` to your Context may help also.